# Control tab not registering in emacs -nw

Tags: emacs

I have this in my .emacs which works in X mode.
(global-set-key [C-tab]    'next-multiframe-window)
I have tried to M-x global-set-key C-tab but only the TAB registers
which successfully remaps tab to 'next-multiframe-window

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/257580/emacs-c-not-working-in-terminal

Answer (score 1):

This is no doubt because your keyboard does not send `C-<tab>` to Emacs in terminal mode. That's normal. What you can do instead is bind a similar key, such as `C-c TAB` (or any other key sequence that your terminal recognizes) to the same command.