# Ctrl+ punctuation keys ( ; : , .) do not work in emacs no window mode inside gnome term

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, emacs

I have setup a few bindings in emacs such as Ctrl + : or Ctrl + ; 
These bindings work in emacs gui mode but when running emacs -nw inside Gnome terminal 3.6 they don't do anything.

My issue is similar to 
[Emacs C-. not working in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257580/emacs-c-not-working-in-terminal?answertab=active#tab-top)
and I am wondering if there is a way to expand the gnome term to actually send those keys.

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-terminal` does not let you redefine the escape sequences, so no, there's nothing you could do there.

In other terminal emulators this might be possible, however, you'd have to create your own escape sequences and configure both your terminal emulator and your emacs accordingly, and it won't be compatible with anyone else's setup.